# Why is Tweepy returning absolutely nothing when retweeting?

Tags: python, tweepy

Hello StackOverflow Community! I have found a very interesting issue with my code (whether it's a bug or not I have no idea) that severely confuses me, and I'm wondering if the helpful people reading this question can help me out.

So currently, I have the simple code below (with the 3 X's representing my keys on my Twitter app):

```
import tweepy

consumer_key = 'XXX'
consumer_secret = 'XXX'
access_token = 'XXX'
access_token_secret = 'XXX'
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

user = api.me()
print('Launching application with user id: ' + user.name)
for follower in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers).items():
    follower.follow()

search = "#kittens AND #cute #puppy -#grumpy -#ugly"
tnumber = 800
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, search).items(tnumber):
    try:
        tweet.retweet()
        print('Found a tweet - Retweeted')
        tweet.favorite()
        print('Favorited tweet')
    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        print(e.reason)
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

If I run this code, naturally it will print the `launching application with...` message. But everything else returns exactly nothing. To put it into further perspective, if I was to run it in a terminal with `py main.py` the console would simply go down a line.

Now obviously this accomplishes the exact opposite of what I want my code to do. So my overall question is (what most people post on Stack Overflow), *why doesn't this work?* But what I'm mainly looking for is, *why does it return absolutely nothing?*

Many thanks for your help

Comment: You don't need to except the `StopInteration` in the for loop.

Comment: @MattM. Thanks for the input

Comment: `tweepy.Cursor(api.search, search).items(tnumber)` contains nothing to iterate over